# Почему не получается горизонтальное выравнивание?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Пытаюсь сделать два `<div>` блока внутри `<div>` ширина которого `400px`. Надо чтобы ширина вложенного дива была `30px`, а всю оставшуюся ширину заполнил первый `<div>`.

Делаю так:

```css
.insert {
  /*height: 36px;*/
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 10px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.filed_input {
  width: 400px;
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.arrow_label {
  width: 30px;
  height: 34px;
}

.arrow_label:before {
  content: '▼';
  top: 7px;
  left: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow_label.on:before {
  content: '▲';
}

.container_field_input {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filed_input div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.filed_input>* {
  vertical-align: top;
}

._input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="filed_input">
  <div class="_input">
    <input type="text" class="insert" />
  </div>
  <div class="arrow_label" id="_arraw_label"></div>
</div>
<div class="filed_list"></div>
```

Но почему-то первый занимает все `100%` и второй уходит на вторую строку.
`Flex`, `grid` не нужны.

---

Вот итоговый, работающий под мою задачу код:`anon/pen/qLwmZQ`

Comment: Не даёт вставить, потому что код должен быть **прямо в тексте вопроса** без всяких там кодепенов. Доведите оформление вопроса до ума

Comment: html & css можно увидеть?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLWbvq

Comment: Вставляю код и такая чушь выходит, не знаю почему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если **без современных** возможностей css (`flex`, `grid`) и если я правильно понимаю задачу, то обертке задаем `position:relative` и отступ равный ширине стрелочки. А самой стрелочке задаем `position:absolute` и выравниваем по вертикали:

```css
.insert {
  /*height: 36px;*/
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 10px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.filed_input {
  width: 400px;
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.arrow_label {
  width: 30px;
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
}

.arrow_label:before {
  content: '▼';
  top: 7px;
  left: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow_label.on:before {
  content: '▲';
}

.container_field_input {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filed_input div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.filed_input>* {
  vertical-align: top;
}

._input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="filed_input">
  <div class="_input">
    <input type="text" class="insert" />
  </div>
  <div class="arrow_label" id="_arraw_label"></div>
</div>
<div class="filed_list"></div>
```

Еще вариант с `display: table`:

```css
.insert {
  /*height: 36px;*/
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 10px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  
  width: 100%;
}

.filed_input {
  width: 400px;
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.arrow_label {
  width: 30px;
  height: 34px;
  
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
}

.arrow_label:before {
  content: '▼';
  top: 7px;
  left: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow_label.on:before {
  content: '▲';
}

.container_field_input {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* .filed_input div {
  display: inline-block;
} */

.filed_input>* {
  vertical-align: top;
}

._input {
  /* width: 100%; */
  
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="filed_input">
  <div class="_input">
    <input type="text" class="insert" />
  </div>
  <div class="arrow_label" id="_arraw_label"></div>
</div>
<div class="filed_list"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не так [Кодик](https://codepen.io/keeplod/pen/LMvVKE) тогда нарисуй мне как ты хочешь)

```
<div class="filed_input">
<div class="_input">
  <div class="arrow_label" id="_arraw_label"></div>
    <input type="text" class="insert"     onclick="toggleDrop(ge('_arraw_label'));"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Сначала строка должна идти, а уже потом стрелочка вниз. Я ведь дал структуру HTML

Comment: В общем сделал через обтекание и почему то работает, кто-нибудь знает почему? То есть если я ставлю кнопку сначала и даю обтекать ее справа-то все работает. как я хочу. Что за магия?
Код-https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BvEWba

Comment: ты поставил float: right; - Выравнивает элемент по правому краю, а все остальные элементы обтекают его по левой стороне.

Comment: А если делаю через левое обтекание-то так не получается почему-то

Comment: вот только что к тебе зашел поменял right на left и поменялось как надо кнопка слева строчка справа

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял тебе нужно в диван(1) уместить диван(2) который 30px и диван(3)  причем 3ий диван нужно чтобы занимал все пространство кроме того что занимает 2ой внутри 1го

Так сделай 2ой диван внутри 3го.

Comment: Место того что бы минусы ставить объясни что нужно...

Comment: я не минусил ответ

Comment: Лудушки) так я правильно понял суть вопроса?